# Induction proof for integrals

Tags: integration, induction

[image: question]

I am having issues with proving the second step, and have been told that it would be best to approach this question by induction. I have manages to get this far:

$$\left(\int_{a}^b g(x)f(x)=\frac{(-1)^{k}}{c^{k}}\int_{a}^b g(x)f^{(k)}(x)\right)\times\frac{-1}{c}$$
$$\frac{-1}{c}\int_{a}^b g(x)f(x)=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{c^{k+1}}\int_{a}^b g(x)f^{(k)}(x)$$
$$-\int_{a}^b g(x)f(x)=\frac{c(-1)^{k+1}}{c^{k+1}}\int_{a}^b g(x)f^{(k)}(x)$$
$$-\int_{a}^b g(x)f(x)=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{c^{k+1}}\int_{a}^b cg(x)f^{(k)}(x)$$
$$-\int_{a}^b g(x)f(x)=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{c^{k+1}}\int_{a}^b g'(x)f^{(k)}(x)$$

From here I have no idea how to produce $f^{(k+1)}(x)$ inside the integral, or whether this was the right way to approach solving this problem. Any pointers with how to proceed would be awesome!

Cheers

Comment: Why do you ask the same question again? I suggest you to remove this one, and add your try in the previous question of yours.

Comment: @mickep mainly because I felt it would not gain any traction if I posted a progress update.

Comment: Nevertheless, that is the way to go... Also, why do you mark an answer as accepted first, and then start to ask questions about it? That does not make sense.

Comment: @mickep Whoops, didn't mean to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose it is true for $n=k$. Accordingly, we assume that the following holds

$$\int_a^b {g(x)f(x)dx = {{{{( - 1)}^k}} \over {{c^k}}}\int_a^b {g(x){f^{(k)}}(x)dx} } $$

Now let's go to see what happens about $n=k+1$. We use integration by parts for the right hand side of the above equation to get

$$\eqalign{
  & \int_a^b {g(x)f(x)dx = \left[ {{{g(x)} \over c}{f^{(k)}}(x)} \right]_a^b - {{{{( - 1)}^k}} \over {{c^k}}}\int_a^b {{{g(x)} \over c}{f^{(k + 1)}}(x)dx} }   \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = 0 + {{{{( - 1)}^{k + 1}}} \over {{c^{k + 1}}}}\int_a^b {g(x){f^{(k + 1)}}(x)dx}   \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = {{{{( - 1)}^{k + 1}}} \over {{c^{k + 1}}}}\int_a^b {g(x){f^{(k + 1)}}(x)dx}  \cr} $$

and hence it is also valid for $n=k+1$. Cheers! :D

---

**Edit**

Integration by parts formula is

$$\eqalign{
  & V(x) = \int_k^x {v(t)dt}  + A  \cr 
  & \int_a^b {u(x)v(x)dx}  = \left[ {u(x)V(x)} \right]_a^b - \int_a^b {V(x)u'(x)dx}  \cr} $$

where $V(x)$ is **an** anti-derivative (or primitive function) of $v(x)$. In your problem we should choose

$$\eqalign{
  & u(x) = {f^{(k)}}(x)  \cr 
  & v(x) = g(x)  \cr 
  & V(x) = \int_k^x {g(t)dt}  + A = \left[ {{{g(t)} \over c}} \right]_k^x + A = {{g(x)} \over c} + \left( { - {{g(k)} \over c} + A} \right) \cr} $$

but since $A$ is arbitrary we can choose $A = {{g(k)} \over c}$ and hence

$$V(x) = {{g(x)} \over c}$$

This will help you to understand the integration by parts done in the above solution.

Comment: Why is it that when you sub in n=k+1 to the fraction ((-1)/c)^(n) it is only ((-1)/c)^(k)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you?

Comment: Here is the whole process. In part (a) you showed that the claim is true for $n=1$. In part (b) you assume that it is true for $n=k$ and then prove that is valid for $n=k+1$. Consequently, it is valid for every integer $n$. That's all.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't very clear what I meant. In the second line of working out I mainly just confused as to how you managed to express the integral on the right hand side in that form.

Comment: Are you familiar with integration by parts? choose $$\eqalign{
  & dv = g(x)dx  \cr 
  & u = {f^{(k)}}(x) \cr} $$

Comment: Yeah I have encountered it, and that was what I used to solve the other part of the question, but honestly I am still not very confident with the concept.

Comment: See the edited answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: you're welcome. :)